# Pass by value don't affect Setter?

Tags: objective-c, pass-by-value

Look a setter like:

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    [newCount retain];
    [_count release];
    // Make the new assignment.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

If I call `[self setCount:anNSNumber]`, the effect will occur (`_count` will be released, `anNSNumber` will be retained, ... as you know). But I know that in Obj-C pass by value is default. So, why that happend ?

Comment: Might you formulate better the question?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is passed by value. In this case the parameter is a pointer. The pointer, not the object, is passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in saying the Objective-C uses pass-by-value; it is not simply the default but the only parameter passing mechanism supported. Objective-C++ supports C++ pass-by-reference as well.

In your expression `[self setCount:anNSNumber]` the *value* in the variable `anNSNumber` is passed to `setCount`. However that value is a *reference* of type `NSNumber *`, and that reference may be used to modify the object that is referenced.

The value that is passed for a parameter is used to initialise a local variable in the callee, and you can modify the value in that variable without any effect on the caller - this is the definition of call-by-value. So for example you could add to your `setCount`:

```
newCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:42];
```

and that would have no effect on the caller.